# How do you import pictures to Python console without other software/add-ons

Tags: python-3.6

I have looked forever and nothing helps to print/add pictures to Python. I don't want to download software or add-ons just plain Python. I have also tried AI and it doesn't help. (PS. I am in Python 3.6)

I have tried EVERYTHING and it ends up in NO CONSOLE NAMED ---- Please help me. Ive also tried CURSES and it doesn't work.

Comment: What make you think it is possible without add-ons?

Comment: A list of included libraries can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html). The closest to image import might be tkinter but it's more of a GUI library and it has a steep learning curve. People usually use the third-party library [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/pillow/) when they want to deal with images.